# How to convert multi-page pdf to single html file

Tags: python, poppler

I'm implementing poppler **pdftohtml** method to convert pdf to html. I'm trying to run the exec file via python.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen([r"D:/poppler-0.68.0/bin/pdftohtml.exe" , 'name.pdf', 'name.html'])
```

Using the above code I'm getting my html file and also the images(.jpg) of each and every page in pdf.

I need only the html file not images. What changes/arguments should i make/add to get my expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [their documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/poppler-utils/pdftohtml.1.en.html) there might be two options that could help you out with that:

`-i ignore images`

and

`-s generate single HTML that includes all pages`

If these don't work, there's nothing else you could do.

Comment: Thank you. it works. I get a html page as output with gray background and black on it. My pdf contains pages with white back ground and black text in it. Also the page seems to be left aligned. Do you know why is it?

Comment: @DGS I would assume it's because of the way `pdftohtml` tool renders it. You could theoretically open the HTML in python and remove any inline style that has `background-color` that applies to the `body` or some other major container, assuming of course that all PDF's have white background.

Comment: I found that only after the addition of -i to the arguments the background turns out to be gray.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`-noframes`**, it will generate one file.

According to `help`:

```
Usage: pdftohtml [options] <PDF-file> [<html-file> <xml-file>]
  -f <int>          : first page to convert
  -l <int>          : last page to convert
  -q                : don't print any messages or errors
  -h                : print usage information
  -help             : print usage information
  -p                : exchange .pdf links by .html
  -c                : generate complex document
  -i                : ignore images
  -noframes         : generate no frames
  -stdout           : use standard output
  -zoom <fp>        : zoom the pdf document (default 1.5)
  -xml              : output for XML post-processing
  -hidden           : output hidden text
  -nomerge          : do not merge paragraphs
  -enc <string>     : output text encoding name
  -dev <string>     : output device name for Ghostscript (png16m, jpeg etc)
  -v                : print copyright and version info
  -opw <string>     : owner password (for encrypted files)
  -upw <string>     : user password (for encrypted files)
```